# I believe this is meant to be solved using double induction, but I cannot figure out the necessary equations.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

If $f_n$ is the $n^{th}$ Fibonacci Number, then prove the following:
$\mathbf{Theorem:}$ For every $k \geq 1$ and $n \geq 1$, if $k|n$, then $f_k|f_n$

Answer (score 2):

Various ways to do this, here is an outline of one.

- Prove by induction on $m$ that $f_{k+m}\equiv f_mf_{k+1}\pmod{f_k}$.
- Then prove by induction on $m$ that $f_{km}\equiv0\pmod{f_k}$.

Comment: I think by what you said this is what I am trying to do. f_{k+(m+1)} = f_{k+m+1} = f_{(k+1)+m} = f_{k+1}f_m